# how to test gesture applicaion in ipad using key board

Tags: ipad, gesture

i dont have device so how can i test double finger touch for rotation and pinch?

Answer (score 1):

Hold down alt key in simulator.

Comment: (Also known as the "Option" key.)

Comment: That the Apple secret handshake - it's the one that says 'alt' on top, so I'm going to stick with that :-).